# Selectively fetching in Core Data for better performance (fetch large items later)

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm working on an iPhone app using a core data store with about 100 entities, each with the following attributes: a few strings, a small thumbnail image, and the full-size image (stored in an External Record File via Core Data).

These are loaded into a Fetched Results Controller for use in a table view. To increase loading speed and decrease memory usage, how can I prevent the full-size image from being fetched until after a cell is selected?

I'm very new to Core Data, but would a Fetched Property be of use here?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this before by moving the image into its own `Entity` in the model and adding a relation back to the original object.

The new object will be something like...

```
Image
----------
image (binary data) - store externally (same as the current image)
----------
object - relation to the original object
```

Then just replace the attribute in the original entity to a relation.

The FRC will then only load the objects and then when you do... `object.image` it will then get the image object that you can get the image out of.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Everything is running so smoothly now. Cheers.